# How do I get to the second floor of the Lecture Building?

Tags: bloodborne

I feel like I have seen every room of this area but I just can't find any ladders or stairs that let me up to the second floor. Is it unlocked later in the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That area is unlocked later on in the game. One of the Bloodborne wiki outlines the [exact criteria](http://bloodborne.wiki.fextralife.com/Lecture+Building+2nd+Floor):

> To get to the Lecture Room 2nd floor, you must first beat the One Reborn, and proceed past him through Advent Plaza, where you will inspect a mummy that teleports you to the 2nd floor lamp of the Lecture Building.